# How to insert Gaussian/Normal distribution in multiple subplots?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

So I have multiple plots, using subplot and I would like to add the Gaussian distribution on it. I have done it, in a for loop for each plot separately, but I am not sure how to do it using subplots. At the moment it does not show anything on the subplots.

```
def index_of(arrval, value):
if value < min(arrval):
    return 0
return max(np.where(arrval <= value)[0])

# load file using loadtxt
for file in filename:
data = np.loadtxt(file,delimiter='\t', skiprows=2)
for x,y in data:
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
xs.append(x)
ys.append(y)

# Make the subplots
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
   ij = np.unravel_index(i, axs.shape)
   axs[ij].plot(x, y,label = lsnames[i])
   axs[ij].set_title(lsnames[i])
   axs[ij].legend()

# Using one of the lmfit functions to get the Gaussian plot.
# But it does not show anything

gauss1 = GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
gauss2 = GaussianModel(prefix='g2_')
pars = gauss1.guess(y, x=x)


pars.update(gauss2.make_params())

ix1 = index_of(x, 20)
ix2 = index_of(x, 40)
ix3 = index_of(x, 75)
gauss1.guess(y[ix1:ix2], x=x[ix1:ix2])
gauss2.guess(y[ix2:ix3], x=x[ix2:ix3])
mod = gauss1 + gauss2

mod = GaussianModel()

pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you just provide a running example with random numbers? Would be easier...

Comment: value count
0 0
1 605
2 1350
3 1721
4 1740
5 1617
6 1357
7 1377
8 768
9 954
10 662
11 660
12 610
13 561
14 570
15 554
16 621
17 676
18 649
19 724
20 795

Comment: This is more or less the type of data I want to plot.

Comment: and you have multiple data sets and you want to create a large figure with subplots (for each data set) and then fit a Gaussian to the data? Is that correct? I'm asking because I don't know what "add a distribution" should mean and I cant find the definition of any subplots in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding, but this seems like it could just be a looping question or even an indentation problem.

I think what you're asking to do is something like:

```
# loop over datasets, putting each in a subplot
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
    ij = np.unravel_index(i, axs.shape)
    axs[ij].plot(x, y,label = lsnames[i])
    axs[ij].set_title(lsnames[i])
    axs[ij].legend()

    # fit this dataset with 1 gaussian
    mod = GaussianModel()
    pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)
    out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)

    # plot best-fit
    axs[ij].plot(x, out.best_fit, label='fit')
    print("Data Set %d" % i)
    print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))

plt.show()
```

Your code was sort of confusingly making a model with two Gaussians and then not using it.  It would be fine to use a more complicated model in the loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was trying to indent and use axs[ij].plot(x,y) I guess I was putting the wrong parameters. Thank you for your help! Really appreciate it!